# Need help in understanding Thread wait and notify

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

```
class Semaphore {
   private int count=100;
   public Semaphore(int n) {
      this.count = n;
   }

   public synchronized void acquire() {
      while(count == 0) {
         try {
            wait();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //keep trying
         }
      }
      count--;
   }

   public synchronized void release() {
      count++;
      notify(); //alert a thread that's blocking on this semaphore
   }
}
```

Currently I am supporting 100 users. If a request comes from the jsp (Client) and goes through this class, will the Thread (the request from JSP ) `wait` and `notify` automatically?

Answer (score 6):

I would highly recommend using the [java.util.concurrent.Semaphore](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) from the standard library instead of writing a custom Semaphore implementation. Only to mention one reason why this generally is a better idea: `notify` does not give any FIFO guarantees (from [Object.notify()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29)):

> The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to write a semaphore yourself.

Take a look at the Java 6 documentation for [Semaphore](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).
and this [tutorial](http://www.tutorials.de/java/178078-beispiel-zum-java-util-concurrent-semaphor.html) from Thomas Darimont.